# Not to apply polyurethane

Tags: wood

I have finished applying a cherry stain to interior French door with trim. I am on the fence about applying polyurethane because I am not convinced that it will look good. Personally I like how it looks without it. It's got a natural-wood feel and look. Has anyone regretted not applying polyurethane?

Comment: Many stains need a finish coat or they will bleed onto hands and clothing that brush against them. Check your can.

Comment: -1 this is a broad/open ended question that may solicit opinions rather than factual answers.

Answer (score 1):

I have never regretted applying poly, although it does cause a slight color change, called "ambering". To me it enhances the color nicely, try it on a scrap of trim  stained and see how you like it. I prefer satin, the reduced glare allows the wood grain to show looking at it in almost any light or direction.

There are other finishes that will not change the color at all, lacquer being one of them, clear shellac is another. It is better to apply by spray, since it dries so quickly, but I think there is a product called Deft that is a brush on lacquer that is highly rated, at least at one time in my understanding.[image][image: shellac2]
Lacquer and shellac does have the advantage drying fast so the airborne dust does not get into the finish

With lacquer and shellac you can "burnish" the dry material with 0000 steel wool to a matte finish to tone the gloss down if you choose.